# Call an ICommand from Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon Event .MouseClick() [WPF Application]

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom `NotifyIcon` object inherited from Window Forms. Looking for the properties and the methods of the NotifyIcon Class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) I saw that I can trigger an Event when the user clicks the NotifyIcon from Taskbar. So I have created the following code inside a ViewModel

```cs
namespace TestEnvironment
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand ShowWindowsCommand //this is the ICommand I want to call in .MouseClick()
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FunctionShowWindows); }
        }
        private void FunctionShowWindows(object parameter)
        {
            ProgressBarTemplate ProgressBarInstance = (ProgressBarTemplate)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(window => window.Name == "ProgressBarScreen");
            if (ProgressBarInstance != null)
            {
                if (MainWindowInstance.MaxHeight > 725 & MainWindowInstance.MaxWidth > 1200)
                {
                    MainWindowInstance.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    MainWindowInstance.Activate();
                    //MainWindowInstance.Topmost = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MainWindowInstance.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    MainWindowInstance.Activate();
                    //MainWindowInstance.Topmost = true;
                }
                ProgressBarInstance.Show();
                ProgressBarInstance.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                //ProgressBarInstance.Topmost = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (MainWindowInstance.MaxHeight > 725 & MainWindowInstance.MaxWidth > 1200)
                {
                    MainWindowInstance.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    MainWindowInstance.Activate();
                    //MainWindowInstance.Topmost = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MainWindowInstance.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    MainWindowInstance.Activate();
                    //MainWindowInstance.Topmost = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand RunCalculationCommand_Approach2
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteSqlAsync); }
        }
        private async void ExecuteSqlAsync(object obj)
        {
            Stream iconStream_one = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TestApp;component/Assets/loading.ico")).Stream;
            
            System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notification_object = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
            {
                Icon = new Icon(iconStream_one),
                Visible = true
            };

            // The complete Task API accepts a CancellationToken to allow cancellation.
            try
            {
                DateTime timestamp_start = DateTime.Now;

                await Task.Run(() => RunCalculationsMethod(object_progressbar, "LOG_DETAILS", 1, true, getconnectionstring, CatchErrorExceptionMessage, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token), this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
                
                string[] time_passed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(timestamp_start).ToString().Split(@":");

                List<SucessfulCompletion> reportsucessfulcompletion = new List<SucessfulCompletion>();
                reportsucessfulcompletion = CheckLogsFailSuccessProcedure(SQLServerConnectionDetails());

                if (reportsucessfulcompletion[0].Result == 0)
                {
                    notification_object.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Hi", "This is a BallonTip from Windows Notification", System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.None);
                    //notification_object.MouseClick += new System.EventHandler(ShowWindowsCommand);
                }
                else
                {
                    notification_object.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Hi", "Hello World", System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.None);
                    //notification_object.MouseClick += new System.EventHandler(ShowWindowsCommand);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //..
            }
            finally
            {
                //..
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
            Closing += CancelSqlOperationsOnClosing;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestEnvironment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEnvironment"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Show Toast"
        Padding="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding RunCalculationCommand_Approach2}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I want is to call the ICommand `ShowWindowsCommand` from the Event `MouseClick`.

`//notification_object.MouseClick += new System.EventHandler(ShowWindowsCommand); -> This is what I want to fix`

But this Event accepts EventHandlers. So, is there any way to call the ICommand from the `MouseClick` event of the `NotifyIcon`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `NotifyIcon` is not actually a control that displays on a page, you can instantiate it in the ViewModel. In order to trigger the command when clicking on the icon, you simply need to implement a callback to the event.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
namespace TestEnvironment
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand ShowWindowsCommand
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FunctionShowWindows); }
        }

        private void FunctionShowWindows(object parameter)
        {
            // redacted
        }

        public ICommand RunCalculationCommand_Approach2
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteSqlAsync); }
        }

        private async void ExecuteSqlAsync(object obj)
        {

            Stream iconStream_one = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TestApp;component/Assets/loading.ico")).Stream;
            
            System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notification_object = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
            {
                Icon = new Icon(iconStream_one),
                Visible = true
            };

            notification_object.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(NotifyIcon_MouseClick);

            // redacted
        }

        private void NotifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e);
        {
            FunctionShowWindows(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello ArwynFr and thanks for your answer. Based on your answer I have to assign my button click the property to ```Image_Click``` which is fine. But how I know that the notifyIcon will also execute the ```ShowWindowsCommand``` ICommand?

Comment: You did not mention a button in your question. For WPF controls, just bind the command. For the NotifyIcon, since it's a Winforms control, binding does not work, that's why you use a callback. See answer edit.

Comment: ArwynFr yeah I have a button. For the button I bind the ICommand ```RunCalculationCommand_Approach2```. But for the notifyIcon I use the second ICommand ```ShowWindowsCommand```. So I have two ICommands. The first one is called on  a Button as you pointed in your answer. But the second ICommand is only called from the NotifyIcon. Also I should remind you that I have a WPF application not a WinForm

Comment: You can bind the Button's Command property because it is a DependencyProperty. NotifyIcon is a WinForm control, so it does not have a one. Whether you're using it in a WinForm or WPF application does not change that. Since it's a WinForm control, you must register an event callback in the view, and implement a method that will call the command in the viewmodel.

Comment: And how do I do this *an event callback in the view, and implement a method that will call the command in the viewmodel*. Also in your answer the code ```<NotifyIcon MouseClick="NotifyIcon_MouseClick" />``` implies an XAML file or a cs.file? Because the code I posted is in a cs.file not an xaml file.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your XAML and xaml.cs files in the question ?

Comment: The event callback goes in the view class (not the viewmodel) ; see edit

Comment: Adding both this ```xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"``` and this ```<forms:NotifyIcon MouseClick="NotifyIcon_MouseClick" />``` got me this error: ```A value of type 'NotifyIcon' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'```

Comment: How do you use the NotifyIcon ?

Comment: I instantiate it in my cs file, like in the code I posted ```System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notification_object = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon```

Comment: You simply register the new method on the event using `+=` operator ; see edit

Comment: I have seen your edit. Keep in mind that the notification_object.MouseClick is called inside my ViewModel and not the view. So running this ```notification_object.MouseClick += new System.EventHandler(NotifyIcon_MouseClick);``` in the ViewModel returns an error that ```NotifyIcon_MouseClick``` does not exist in the context. Along with this edit please check this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0 Microsoft article from where I took the idea. Although in this article the code is inside the view not an MVVM ViewModel.

Comment: if you create `notification_object` in your viewmodel class, then it won't display on the view

Comment: It is displayed normally when my application runs. I mean that I can see the notification on my laptop. But I want to also click the small icon on the taskbar and execute the ```ShowWindowsCommand```. This implementation is similar to the ```TaskbarIcon``` of Hardcodet nuget package. The TaskbarIcon has a functionality called ```LeftClickCommand```. For more check here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2

Comment: Ok, now I understand ; NotifyIcon is not an actually a control (that displays in your page) !

Comment: Since you create the NotifyIcon in the viewmodel you can directly call the FunctionShowWindows method from the event callback. see edit

Comment: I made a small edit to your code. The edit I made worked as expected in my runtime. Thanks a lot for your help ArwynFr. We had a long conversation and I am glad that you helped me to solve this.